# MySQL and server settings when upgrading Mac Pro from 10.6 to 10.7

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, upgrade, mac-pro

I have my web development environment on a mac pro running on OS X version 10.6.
I'm considering upgrading it to Mac OS X 10.7.

Will it upgrade smoothly or do I have to reinstall mysql, perl and so on? 
I am especially scared for upgrading MySQL and the databases.

To answer remarks here below, I don't remember how I installed MySQL in the first place, but for what I remember, it didn't came out of the box. That's why I am scared it might get removed.

Concerning the os version, I tend to say as close possible to the version that came with the mac at the time. The more recent the OS the more resource hungry they are. I prefer to have a fast mac then an up to date OS. I would stay to 10.6, but there are some applications could help me and are only running on 10.7.

Comment: Is your current MySQL compatible with Mountain Lion?

Comment: How did you install MySQL - also what is your reason for upgrading and why not directly to 10.9? or just leave at 10,6

Comment: I upgraded my question to answer your questions

Comment: Usually my MySQL installation works after upgrading. You may want to review your php.ini to correct the position of the MySQL socket (php.ini gets changed by the upgrades). http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/macosx-installation-notes.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL, as well as the databases, is still there and working after upgrading. This said, all the settings, php, mysql, apache, virtual hosts, where resetted to the default. Very annoying I have to rebuild all my development environment.